# Angular 2/4 pushing in array inside an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been trying to push some comments in an array inside an object(Object is not an array but there is array in it) I spent quite a time cant get it to work. What I have is

```
export class test{
     recordname: string;
     comments: [{
         comment: string
      }]
}
```

Each time some one types a comment I want to add it to the comment array something like this

```
  addcomment: test;
addRow(){
    this.addcomment.comment.push({
        comment : 'first comment'})
```

I tried to add it using different ways cant seem to make it work. The message i get push is undefined. I cant use addcomment:test[]=[]; since this is form where vlaues are input and saved. 
Please let me know how can I push comment values

Comment: spelling mistake,  this.addcomment.comment.push({
        comment : 'first comment'}) has to be comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example creates a new `RecordItem` which we can subsequently push items into, initialising an empty `recordName` and `comment` array.

```
export class Comment {
  comment: string
}

export class RecordItem {
  recordName: string;
  comments: Comment[]

  constructor(recordName: string, comments: Comment[]) {
    this.recordName = recordName;
    this.comments = comments;
  }
}

const recordItem = new RecordItem('', []);

recordItem.comments.push({ comment: 'Hey!!' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling mistake on addcomment.comment (comments)
Like this. 1. Define comments as an array. 2. Then just use the push function and pass in an object.

```
  export class test{
         recordname: string;
         comments: any[];
    }

this.addcomment.comments.push({
    comment : 'first comment'})
```

Comment: typographical errors have to be commented and the question probably closed.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to initialize always yours objects and array... you can do it in different ways so for example ...

```
export class test{
         recordname: string;
         comments: any[] = []; //set it as empty array ...intilized
    }

addcomment: test = new test(); //<-- INITIALIZE IT
addRow(){
    this.addcomment.comment.push({
        comment : 'first comment'});
}
```

Or if you don't like this approch ...

```
addcomment: test = new test(); //<-- INITIALIZE IT
    addRow(){

//check if nested array is undefined ..or other
 if(!this.addcomment.comment || this.addcomment.comment.length<=0)
     {
       this.addcomment.comment =[]; //<-- INITIALIZE AS EMPTY ARRAY
     }
        this.addcomment.comment.push({
            comment : 'first comment'});
    }
```

Hope it helps you!!